# iOS 15 UITabBarItem customization

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem, uiappearance, ios15

I have `UITabBarConroller` subclass and custom items. Customization looks like this:

```
private func updateTabBar() {
    guard let items = tabBar.items,
        tabViewControllers.count == items.count else {
        return
    }

    for (item, vc) in zip(items, tabViewControllers) {
        // setting items title, image, selectedImage ...
        item.setTitleTextAttributes(Self.normalAttributes, for: .normal)
        item.badgeColor = .customColor
    }
}
```

This works fine on iOS 14 and earlier. But not on iOS 15. I have found some information about `scrollEdgeAppearance`. This prevents black background. But setting colored text attributes and badge color is ignored.
The question is how to set custom text color and badge color on the `UITabBarItem`?

Comment: You might want to show your configuration for standardAppeararanc and scrollEdgeAppearance. Btw. as far as I know there was no changes to badgeColor in ios15.

Comment: "cutomization"?

Comment: @kironet, but badgeColor becomes system-red in iOS 15 :(

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I did it. I was looking for `stackedLayoutAppearance` and its properties `iconColor` and `badgeBackgroundColor`. Depending on your project you may need also `inlineLayoutAppearance` or `compactInlineLayoutAppearance`.

```
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
private static let tabBarAppearance: UITabBarAppearance = {
    let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = .customBackgroundColor
            
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.iconColor = .customTitleColorForNormalState
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = normalAttributes
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = normalAttributes
    appearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.badgeBackgroundColor = .customBadgeColor
    return appearance
}()
```

And I use this static constant in my loop through all UITabBarItems:

```
if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
    item.standardAppearance = Self.tabBarAppearance
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        item.scrollEdgeAppearance = item.standardAppearance
    }
}
```

Comment: My god they made something that was one line and completely obvious into this