# Remove border top, change font family,.... not working in Xamarin iOS latest version

Tags: xamarin

In my Xamarin iOS app I am trying to hide the top border and change the font family of TabbedPage. For Xamarin version 5.0.0.2021 it works fine. However when I update Xamarin version to 5.0.0.2244 it doesn't seem to work? There must be something unusual here. This is how I changed the font Family and Border Top TabbedPage:

**MyTabbedPageRenderer**

*Change icon size, fontsize, font family,... TabbedPage*

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
....
public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
{

    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        TabBar.TintColor = UIColor.Gray;
        TabBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.White;
        TabBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
    }
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        if (TabBar?.Items == null)
            return;

        foreach (var item in TabBar.Items)
        {
            item.Image = ScalingImageToSize(item.Image, new CGSize(30, 30)); // set the size here as you want 
        }

        var tabs = Element as TabbedPage;
        if (tabs != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < TabBar.Items.Length; i++)
            {
                UpdateTabBarItem(TabBar.Items[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    private void UpdateTabBarItem(UITabBarItem item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;

        // Set the font for the title.
        item.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes() { Font = UIFont.FromName("Quicksand Regular", 12), TextColor = Color.FromHex("#808080").ToUIColor() }, UIControlState.Normal);
        item.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes() { Font = UIFont.FromName("Quicksand Regular", 13), TextColor = Color.FromHex("#00AA13").ToUIColor() }, UIControlState.Selected);

    }
    ...

}
```

*Remove border top TabbedPage*

AppDelegate

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{

    UITabBar.Appearance.BackgroundImage = new UIImage();
    UITabBar.Appearance.ShadowImage = new UIImage();
    UITabBar.Appearance.SelectedImageTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(0, 170, 19);

    LoadApplication(new App());
}
```

I tried rebuilding the project, restarting everything, but it doesn't seem to work on Xamarin version 5.0.0.2244. Ask for help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some api changes in iOS 15, so we need to change the way .

##### Remove border top

```
TabBar.ClipsToBounds = true;
```

##### Change the font and text color on items

```
private void UpdateTabBarItem(UITabBarItem item)
{
  if (item == null) return;

  if(UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
  {
      UITabBarAppearance app = new UITabBarAppearance();
      app.ConfigureWithOpaqueBackground();
      app.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

      app.StackedLayoutAppearance.Normal.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { Font = UIFont.FromName("GillSans-UltraBold", 12), ForegroundColor = Color.FromHex("#00FF00").ToUIColor() };
      app.StackedLayoutAppearance.Selected.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes() { Font = UIFont.FromName("GillSans-UltraBold", 20), ForegroundColor = Color.FromHex("#FF0000").ToUIColor() };
      item.StandardAppearance = app;

      if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(15, 0))
      {
           item.ScrollEdgeAppearance = item.StandardAppearance;
      }
   }
}
```

Tested on my side , works fine .

Refer to

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69361301/8187800.